# Conditional permission by snapshot name?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'd like to create an IAM policy that gives permissions based on a snapshot name, is this possible? Can't seem to find it in the AWS docs or anyone asking for something similiar.

Essentially if my snapshot is

```
mysnapshot-created-at-10-09
```

I want my AWS policy to have the condition

```
"Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:Name": "mysnapshot*"
                }
            },
```

But it seems you can only do SnapshotID? Which is just a random set of characters. Unfortunately tagging is not available to me in this scenario

Comment: Well, its not supported, so you can't do that.

Comment: What are you wanting to achieve? Have you considered putting the wildcard in the `Resource` instead?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein resource doesn't work as the resource ARN for a snapshot uses the ID, not the name

Comment: @Marcin was hoping for something else but oh well